# Отправка изображения на сервер, обработка с помощью Python и отправка обратно приложению на Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, python, flask

Я хочу сделать программу для *Android (Java)* устройства, которая с помощью *Python* обрабатывает изображение. Я не знаю можно ли использовать *Python* код на *Android* совместно с *Java* и как это сделать и первое что пришло в голову как аналог решения, это: **Отправка изображения на сервер с помощью *Java*, *Python* его получает, обрабатывает и возвращает, устройство его принимает и к примеру выводит на экран**. С помощью каких библиотек это можно сделать? Возможно ли получение изображения с помощью *Flask*?

Comment: Также уточню почему не подходит обработка изображения на устройстве, будет производится обработка с помощью ИИ, то есть затрачивается много ресурсов, что не очень приемлемо.

Comment: просто хотите делать фото и отправлять его на сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте restAPI на питоне с помощью того самого Flask, на андроиде для отправки используйте библиотеку retrofit. Смысла код приводить особого не вижу, попробуйте сами, если что-то не получится - создавайте еще вопросы